# Receptacle fire repair

Tags: repair, receptacle

Hot wire had burned through due to AC cranked on high. 15 amp Breaker did not trip.  I added a jumper to the hot and replaced the receptacle, matching the original installation.  When I tried to connect the hot jumper, it caught fire. Old house, wiring 40 years old. I will hire an electrician, but what is wrong?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. What do you mean "hot jumper"? A photo would help (and an electrician would probably help more).

Comment: FPE breaker and old dead A/C that's pulling too many amps? I have one of those, never new a Kill-a-Watt could scream in pain.

Comment: Or Zinsco... timeframe matches. Take a photo of your electrical panel.

Comment: Can you post a photo of your electrical panel please? This could be a far bigger job than fixing a receptacle burnout...